# Is there an industry specific term for hard backed movie posters?

Tags: terminology, posters

I'm trying to find the value of a movie poster (for Gladiator, not that it matters...) and it's unlike any other poster I've ever seen. Most posters I've ever had were printed on paper and rolled into a scroll. Some of these are mounted in frames or on boards, but this hard-backed poster is different. It seems as if the poster is printed on the board itself! My Googling isn't able to find anything like it, and I am wondering if there's some industry specific term for this style of poster.

Comment: Are you looking for [movie **placard**](https://www.pinterest.ca/cscotr/movie-posters-placards/)?

Comment: @Jeeped I don't understand the difference between poster and placard

Comment: A movie *placard* is typically ¼ inch 'poster board' with a promotional image either glued or printed directly upon it.

Comment: @Jeeped that looks like an answer, please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @Luciano - I was waiting for some confirmation from the OP. Just as we shouldn't answer in comments, we shouldn't play Whack-a-Mole in answers either.